# How do I create this XML programatically from my Activity?

Tags: android, xml

So I know how to create each or all of these elements programatically but I am not sure how to place these LinearLayouts with weights etc, can someone perhaps help me a bit with generating the following XML programatically?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:background="@drawable/background_main"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:id="@+id/main"
          tools:context=".MainActivity"
          android:weightSum="3">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sa_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/sa_id_small"
            android:onClick="onSAIDClicked"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFF"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/phone_number"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:hint="Pin Code"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="numberPassword"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textColorHint="#FFF"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/pin"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:onClick="onButtonClicked"
            android:text="Register"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/usa_drivers"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/usa_drivers_dc_small"
            android:onClick="onUSADriversClicked"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/usa_passport"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/usa_passport_small"
            android:onClick="onUSAPassportClicked"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks,
Wihan

Comment: why would you want to do that programatically?

Comment: Because I need to draw these elements dynamically from a database... Why does it matter why?

Comment: draw?  what do you want to draw?  what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

you can use following example:

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
childParam1.weight = 0.3f;
child1.setLayoutParams(childParam1);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams childParam2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
childParam1.weight = 0.7f;
child2.setLayoutParams(childParam2);

parent.setWeightSum(1f);
parent.addView(child1);
parent.addView(child2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. For e.g :

```
        // Create a new RelativeLayout
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // Defining the RelativeLayout layout parameters.
        // In this case I want to fill its parent
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        setContentView(relativeLayout, layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

To programmatically set the layout weight, and other layout settings, on the `LinearLayout`, set the properties on an instance of [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html). The layout weight is the third argument to the constructor here.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                             LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1.0f);
layout.setLayoutParams(param);
```

The [`LinearLayout` API Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) will provide more detail on the various properties and setters for encoding the data from your XML.

In general, depending on what you're trying to do, it might be better to define the layout in your XML, give the relevant elements IDs, and then access them programmatically using `findViewById(R.id.yourElementId)`.

If you're ever in doubt over which methods to use, or moving between the XML and the Java API, the documentation is a good first stop. Take a look at the docs for [`Button`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) and [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily like this:

In following example `Switch`, `TextView` and `Relative View` are programaticaly created from activity, and you don't need to use 
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`
just use this code after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` and execute.

```
//UI Views
Switch btn_toggle_location, btn_toggle_state;
TextView txt_log;
RelativeLayout ad_container_top;
RelativeLayout ad_container_bottom;
RelativeLayout main_layout;

//Define properties of Switch 1
btn_toggle_location = new Switch(this);
btn_toggle_location.setChecked(true);
btn_toggle_location.setClickable(true);
btn_toggle_location.setId(1);

//Define properties of Switch 2
btn_toggle_state = new Switch(this);
btn_toggle_state.setChecked(true);
btn_toggle_state.setClickable(true);
btn_toggle_state.setId(2);

//Define properties of TextView 
txt_log = new TextView(this);
txt_log.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
txt_log.setId(3);

//Define Layout parameters
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_btn_location = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params_btn_location.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
params_btn_location.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
btn_toggle_location.setLayoutParams(params_btn_location);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_btn_state = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params_btn_state.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 0);
params_btn_state.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, btn_toggle_location.getId());
btn_toggle_state.setLayoutParams(params_btn_state);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_log = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params_log.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, btn_toggle_state.getId());
params_log.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
txt_log.setLayoutParams(params_log);

//Add switch click listeners
btn_toggle_location.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        ad_container_bottom.removeAllViews();
        ad_container_top.removeAllViews();
        txt_log.setText("");
        if (isChecked) {


        } else {

        }
    }
});

btn_toggle_state.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        txt_log.setText("");
        if (isChecked) {

        } else {

        }
    }
});

main_layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams main_lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

ad_container_top = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_top = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout_top.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
layout_top.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout_top.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
ad_container_top.setLayoutParams(layout_top);

ad_container_bottom = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_bottom = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layout_bottom.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
layout_bottom.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
layout_bottom.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
ad_container_bottom.setLayoutParams(layout_bottom);

//Set view visibility
ad_container_bottom.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
ad_container_top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


//Finally add all views to main layout here
main_layout.addView(btn_toggle_location, params_btn_location);
main_layout.addView(btn_toggle_state, params_btn_state);
main_layout.addView(txt_log, params_log);
main_layout.addView(ad_container_top, layout_top);
main_layout.addView(ad_container_bottom, layout_bottom);
main_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
this.addContentView(main_layout, main_lp);
```